# how to impose that $y_i = 0 $ if $q_i> C$

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

How Can I impose that $y_i = 0 $ if $q_i> C$
where C is  a constant
My problem is defined by those constraints:
$$x_i \in \{0 ; 1\}$$
$$q_i \in R^+_0$$
$$y_i \ge x_i - x_{i+1}$$
$$y_i \le x_{i}$$
$$y_i \le 1 - x_{i+1}$$
$y_i$ is defined to detect the transition $x_1=0 \rightarrow x_{i+1}=1$
$$x_i*q_{min} \le q_i \le x_i*q_{max}$$
$q_{min}$ and $q_{max}$ are constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint
$$q>C \Rightarrow y=0$$ 
can be rewritten as:
$$y=1 \Rightarrow q \le C$$
A standard formulation is:
$$
\begin{align}
&q \le C + M (1-y)\\
&y \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}
$$
where $M=q_{max}-C$.